# Update list item from within list item

Tags: 2007, workflow, updatelistitems

I have a list in SharePoint 2007 with a Person or Group type column, named "Attendees" which can contain multiple persons. I want to update Attendees with the logged-in user name on click of a custom link on the form which I have inserted. I was thinking of triggering a workflow which will update the list item, but am not sure how to trigger the update workflow. I am not using nay coding but only SharePoint Designer. Any leads or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update a listitem or start a workflow without server side code, then in SP2007 you only option is to use the Web Services.

If you want to do it directly in javascript on a form I'd recommend that you use [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/), which is a jQuery library for SharePoint, that amonst other allow you to [update a list item](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UpdateListItems&referringTitle=Lists) or [start a workflow](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=StartWorkflow&referringTitle=Workflow)

Comment: If all that author wants is to fill in the form field with current logged in user, then i think it would be much better just to use mentioned SPServices library to fill in the form field with javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. However I am a bit reluctant in doing any sort of customization as we already are in the process of migrating to SP2010. I am still not sure how will this behave in the new environment. Any guidance if its safe to implement at this stage?

Comment: ??? If you don't want to change anything then why the question of how to do it?